# Windows 8 recognizes Sennheiser XSW wireless presentation set as headphones

Tags: windows-8, audio, microphone, headphones, plug-and-play

I'm trying to connect [Sennheiser XSW 12 wireless presentation set](http://en-de.sennheiser.com/wireless-lavalier-clip-on-microphone-system-speakers-presenters-xsw-12) to an Asus S56C laptop running Windows 8. The laptop has combo mic/headphones input and recognizes the device as 'headphones' however something like 'mic' is expected.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried jack-minijack bridge but it did not work. After soldering 4-pin minijack (mic and ground inputs) http://www.thomann.de/gb/thomann_klinkenstecker_35mm_4_pol.htm instead of the jack  and updating sound dirvers got it working.